# How to do element-wise multiplication of a matrix of scalars with a matrix of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I transform the following numpy array A of the form

```
[[1,2]
 [3,4]]
```

into B of the form

```
[[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
 [[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]]
```

such that I can do an element-wise multiplication with C

```
[[[ 5, 6, 7],[ 8, 9,10]]
 [[11,12,13],[13,15,16]]]
```

?

The original problem is to multiply a scalar with a vector, e.g. `4 * [13,15,16]`. But instead of a scalar I have a matrix of scalars (A) and instead of a vector I have a matrix of vectors (C). If there is a way without actually replicating the values like in B I would prefer that (the obvious for-loop will be too slow I guess).

Comment: Hmm, I think I just got it: `A[:,:,None] * C` But I haven't quite understood what's going on here.

Comment: You can also do `A[..., None] * C`, which will work for any number of dimensions, not only for two.

Comment: @neo, what's going on here is that you've discovered [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already mentioned the answer in the comments:

```
A[:,:,None] * C
```

The reason why this works is because numpy interprets a `None` slice as a `newaxis`. From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Each newaxis object in the selection tuple serves to expand the dimensions of the resulting selection by one unit-length dimension. The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.

So that slice is equivalent to doing this:

```
A.reshape(len(A), -1, 1)*C
```

And since I assume these are numpy `array`s, multiplication is of course elementwise by default.

Comment: More info at [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: `reshape` doesn't modify `A` so the end example would still give a broadcast error.  Perhaps you mean: `A.reshape(len(A), -1, 1)*C`, which gives the equivalent result.

Comment: Ah, right you are. and I even had a REPL open when I did that. =X Fixed.

Comment: Just for documentation: `A[:,:,None]` then yields `[[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]` and thus has shape `(2,2,1)` which in turn makes it broadcastable to `C`s shape `(2,2,3)` and thus enables the multiplication -- because broadcasting implicitly expands `(2,2,1)` to `(2,2,3)` by repeating the values (not literally but just internally as part of for-loops).

Comment: One more thing. I think I understood why my example didn't simply work although the simpler case did (scalar and vector). It's probably because scalars are handled specially when broadcasting and are equivalent to one-element arrays with the shape `(1)` which then leads to valid broadcasting. So, if I had expressed my scalars in `A` as one-element arrays inside the given matrix it would just have worked. It's more a theoretical viewpoint but still interesting.